# Does SNMP Null terminate SnmpAdminString’s?

Tags: c, snmp, net-snmp

I am porting some net-snmp agent code to a system. In that process, I am having to learn about all the predefined objects. My question is: Does SNMP null terminate its admin strings?

I have gone through some RFC’s and have read various MIB’s but I just cannot find the information on Null-termination anywhere. The particular admin string is being used as a name/index for an object. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, every object encoding includes a length, so the `NUL` terminator is not used.

Comment: That makes sense. If that is the case, it would also make sense that say a string of 5 NULL's would be a valid Admin string as long as the encoding specifies the length is 5, as a NULL is a valid UTF-8 character. SNMP is an interesting protocol.

Comment: Keep in mind that certain types ("textual conventions", technically speaking) impose certain requirements. For example, I don't think it's valid to have a `NUL` character in a `DisplayString`, but it is true that you could have an `OCTET_STRING` of all `NUL` bytes